# Rephrasing Baby Rudin's theorems 3.33 and 3.34 as more rigid

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The theorems of interest are the a-parts of Rudin's proofs for the root test and the ratio test. In particular,

> Theorem 3.33: Given $\sum a_n$, put $\alpha = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup \sqrt[n]{\left|a_n\right|}$. Then a.) If $\alpha < 1$, $\sum a_n$ converges.

> Theorem 3.34: The series $\sum a_n$, a.) converges if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| = \rho < 1$

In both proofs for the a-parts it is stated quite reasonably that if the condition of the a-part holds, we can find such $N$ that i.) $\sqrt[n]{\left|a_n\right|} < \beta$, ii.) $\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| < \beta$ for $\beta < 1$ for $n \geq N$. But how would you argue about it "more" rigidly, from the definition of a limit. That is, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exits $N_1, N_2$ s.t. i.) $\left|\sqrt[n]{\left|a_n\right|} - \alpha \right| < \epsilon$ for $n \geq N_1$, ii.) $\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} - \rho\right| < \epsilon$, for $n \geq N_2$?

Comment: Choose $\epsilon = (1-\alpha)/2$ ...

Comment: @MartinR I see. It was as simple as expanding the absolute value inequality...